# WebRTC MediaRecorder on remote stream cuts when the stream hangs

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming, webrtc

#### The Problem:

During a WebRTC unicast video conference, I can successfully stream video from a mobile device's webcam to a laptop/desktop. I would like to record the remote stream on the laptop/desktop side. (The setup is that a mobile device streams to a laptop/desktop).

However, it is usual for the video stream to hang from time to time. That's not a problem, for the "viewer" side will catch up. However, the recording of the remote stream will stop at the first hang.

#### Minimal and Removed Implementation (Local Recording):

I can successfully record the local stream from `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` as follows:

```
const recordedChunks = [];

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: false
}).then(stream => {
    const localVideoElement = document.getElementById('local-video');
    localVideoElement.srcObject = stream;
    return stream;
}).then(stream => {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
        if(event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
            recordedChunks.push(event.data);
        }
    };
    mediaRecorder.start({ mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9' }, 10);
});
```

I can download this quite easily as follows:

```
const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: 'video/webm' });

const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const a = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = 'display: none';
a.href = url;
a.download = 'test.webm';
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

#### Minimal and Removed Implementation (Remote Recording):

The setup I am using requires recording the remote stream, not the local stream, for IOS Safari does not support the MediaRecorder API. I included the above to show that the recording is working on the local side. The implementation of the remote stream recording is no different except I manually add a 0 Hz audio track to the video, for Chrome appears to have a bug where it won't record without an audio track.

```
const mediaStream = new MediaStream();
const audioContext = new AudioContext();

const destinationNode = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();

const oscillatorNode = audioContext.createOscillator();
oscillatorNode.frequency.setValueAtTime(0, audioContext.currentTime);
oscillatorNode.connect(destinationNode);

const audioTrack = destinationNode.stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
const videoTrack = remoteStream.getVideoTracks()[0]; // Defined somewhere else.

mediaStream.addTrack(videoTrack);
mediaStream.addTrack(audioTrack);
```

And then I perform the exact same operations that I do on the local stream example above to record the `mediaStream` variable.

As mentioned, at the first point where the remote stream hangs (due to network latency, perhaps), the remote recording ceases, such that on download, the duration of the `.webm` file converted to `.mp4`, via `ffmpeg`, is only as long as to where the first hang occurred.

#### Attempts to Mitigate:

One attempt to mitigate this issue I have tried is, rather than recording the remote stream that is attained in the callback for the `ontrack` event from WebRTC, I use the video stream from the remote video element instead, via `remoteVideoElement.captureStream()`. This does not work to fix the issue.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I've never had any trouble with Chrome recording without an audio track.  Can you link to the bug tracker entry for it?  As to your main problem, I suspect that the parameters of the incoming video are changing and it's hitting a bug/edge case in MediaRecorder.  For example, after dropping out and coming back, it might be at half the resolution.  I've recorded these with MediaRecorder and local devices where the camera resolution drops down due to resource constraints, but haven't tried with remote streams.  In theory it makes no different, but I'm guessing that's where the problem is.

Comment: Given your knowledge on the topic, you might consider joining video-dev on Slack if you're not already a member.  Some of the browser devs hang out there.  http://video-dev.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @Brad Thanks for the insight. I just joined the Slack Group. Another such edge case may be deltas in aspect ratio due to autorotation of the mobile device. As for the bug tracker entry: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=760760

Comment: Yeah, that sounds similar!  I don't know if there's a renegotiation on rotate or not... I suspect not, since the new frame size can just be sent directly.  Frame scaling for sure does not require renegotiation.

Comment: @Brad Well, I'll link to this question in the Slack Group you sent me, and I'll let you know if I find anything out. Are there any other solutions you might suggest? I can't record the local stream because it's mobile phones that are the devices doing the streaming, and Safari on IOS does not support MediaRecorder. I also can't record through a media server because, as you know, STUN is used 70 percent of the time for peer-to-peer.

Comment: @Brad In terms of hitting an edge case with the MediaRecorder API, I've got to imagine that the stream momentarily dropping out, hanging, or losing quality due to latency has got to be pretty common though, right? But I guess resource constraints on a device are slightly different to network latency. I'll monitor the `onnegotiationneeded` event nontheless to check. I also would have thought that recording the `captureStream` from the HTML Video Element would have fixed this, but it didn't. Thanks.

Comment: It's my understanding that at the point of MediaStream, you're dealing with raw frames anyway and are out of territory of the original video codec and stream.  (Even if you're not using the captureStream like you are.)  However, if that original stream somehow indicates that it has stopped, or if the timestamps get wonky, or if MediaRecorder has an issue with a combination of changes, there may be a bug you're bumping up into.  I'm not certain.

Comment: @Brad New bug filed: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=945180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, someone is able to post an actual fix for you.  In the mean time, a nasty, inefficient, totally-not-recommended workaround:

1. Route the incoming MediaStream to a video element.
2. Use `requestAnimationFrame()` to schedule drawing frames to a canvas.  (Note that this removes any sense of genlock from the original video, and is not something you want to do.  Unfortunately, we don't have a way of knowing when incoming frames occur, as far as I know.)
3. Use CanvasCaptureMediaStream as the video source.
4. Recombine the video track from CanvasCaptureMediaStream along with the audio track from the original MediaStream in a new MediaStream.
5. Use this new MediaStream for MediaRecorder.

I've done this with past projects where I needed to programatically manipulate the audio and video.  It works!

One big caveat is that there's a bug in Chrome where even though a capture stream is attached to a canvas, the canvas won't be updated if the tab isn't active/visible.  And, of course, requestAnimationFrame is severely throttled at best if the tab isn't active, so you need another frame clock source.  (I used audio processors, ha!)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @JamieCorkhill I forked off some of this code awhile back from one of my projects... you might find this helpful:  https://github.com/fbsamples/Canvas-Streaming-Example

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks. I'll look into it some more. I appreciate your help.